# how to write perfect loop for the given equation?

Tags: python

i want to write a for loop in python for equation given below:
[image]

Z3 is a matrix of size M*d.

the function JSD is:

```
def JSD(p, q, alpha):
  return np.sum(np.sqrt(p+alpha) * np.log(np.sqrt(p+alpha) / np.sqrt(q+alpha)))


similarity = 0
for i in range(Z3.shape[0]):
  for j in range(Z3.shape[0]): 
    if (Z3[j] != Z3[i]).all():
      m = 0.5*(Z3[i]+Z3[j])
      similarity += 0.5*JSD(Z3[i],m,2)+0.5*JSD(Z3[j],m,2)

print(similarity)
```

how to write perfect code for the above equation?

Answer (score 1):

```
def JSD(p, q, alpha):
  return np.sum(np.sqrt(p+alpha) * np.log(np.sqrt(p+alpha) / np.sqrt(q+alpha)))


similarity = 0
for i in range(Z3.shape[0]):
  for j in range(Z3.shape[0]): 
    if (j != i):
      m = 0.5*(Z3[i]+Z3[j])
      similarity += 0.5*JSD(Z3[i],m,2)+0.5*JSD(Z3[j],m,2)

print(similarity)
```